# CSS class selector for single page

Tags: css

I have this code and I want to remove this image [www.testsite.com/images-5.jpg](http://www.testsite.com/images-5.jpg) by using CSS (using display: none). I tried every selector I can think of but it won't work. I need the full selector from this page not for all pages. In chrome inspect element section i get only the {element_style} without any css reference.

This is my markup:

```
<body data-rsssl="1" class="post-template-default single single-post postid-18069 single-format-standard wpb-js-composer js-comp-ver-6.4.1 vc_responsive cookies-set cookies-accepted" data-header-style="header-style-one" data-nicescroll-cursorcolor="#ffbc13" data-nicescroll-cursorwidth="7px">
    
    <div class="overlay"></div>
                    <div class="radiantthemes-website-layout full-width">
            
        <header class="wraper_header style-one static-header">
    
            <div id="sticky-wrapper" class="sticky-wrapper" style="height: 51px;"><div class="wraper_header_main i-am-sticky" style="">
            <div class="container">
            
            <div class="header_main">
                            
                <div class="header_main_action">
                    
                            <ul class="social">
                                                                                                    <li class="facebook"><a href=#><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            </ul>
                                                                                                                                                        <li class="header-hamburger">
                                                                                                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                                                            </li>
                                            
                </div>
                <!-- header_main_action -->
                                    <!-- responsive-nav -->
                    <div class="responsive-nav hidden-lg hidden-md visible-sm visible-xs">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </div>
                    <!-- responsive-nav -->
                                
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- header_main -->
        </div>
    </div></div>
    <!-- wraper_header_main -->
</header>
<!-- wraper_header -->

    <!-- mobile-menu -->
    <div class="mobile-menu hidden">
        <!-- mobile-menu-main -->
        <div class="mobile-menu-main">
            <!-- mobile-menu-close -->
            <div class="mobile-menu-close">
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
            </div>
            <!-- mobile-menu-close -->
           
        </div>
        <!-- mobile-menu-main -->
    </div>
    <!-- mobile-menu -->


        <!-- hamburger-menu-holder -->
        <div class="hamburger-menu-holder hidden">
            <!-- hamburger-menu -->
            <div class="hamburger-menu">
                <!-- hamburger-menu-close -->
                <div class="hamburger-menu-close">
                    <div class="hamburger-menu-close-lines"><span></span><span></span></div>
                </div>
                <!-- hamburger-menu-close -->
                
            </div>
            <!-- hamburger-menu -->
        </div>
        <!-- hamburger-menu-holder -->

                                <!-- wraper_header_bannerinner -->
                            <div class="wraper_inner_banner" style="background-image:url('www.testsite.com/images-5.jpg')">
                                <!-- wraper_inner_banner_main -->
            <div class="wraper_inner_banner_main">
                <div class="container">
                    <!-- row -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <!-- inner_banner_main -->
                            
                            <!-- inner_banner_main -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- row -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- wraper_inner_banner_main -->
                                </div>
        <!-- wraper_header_bannerinner -->
<!-- wraper_header_bannerinner -->


        <!-- #page -->
        <div id="page" class="site">
            <!-- #content -->
            <div id="content" class="site-content">
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main">
        <!-- wraper_blog_main -->
        <section class="wraper_blog_main">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- row -->
                <div class="row">
                                                                        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 pull-left">
                                                                    <!-- blog_single -->
                        <div class="blog_single">
                            <article id="post-18069" class="single-post post-18069 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-noutati category-anunturi-publice">
    <header class="entry-header">
        
        </div>          </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
            </header></body>
```

Comment: The link redirects me to a "domain for sale" page, and can you also show me your CSS?

Answer (score 0):

The image you want to remove is not held in an img element as far as I can see. The only reference to it in the code you give is as a background-image.

Therefore, display: none is not appropriate as you would be getting rid of the whole element which may not be what you want.

This particular page has a class of postid-18069 and that seems to be the only way of making sure you are going to get rid of the background image on this page only.

So the CSS needs to be something like:

```
.postid-18069 div.wraper_inner_banner {
  background-image: none !important;
}
```

Sadly the !important is probably needed here as otherwise the inline style will overwrite things.

I think that selection is enough, but if not put in more things that come between the .postid-18069 and the background-image div.

Note: this looks like some sort of CMS site (?wordpress?). If so be aware that the postid of that page might change so I am not happy that this is a caste-iron way of removing that image. It might be better to look at the single.php for that site (or whatever is generating that page) and remove having that image, but we'd need to know more about the circumstances before looking into that.